# Statistical power of unit root test

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, unit-root

When studying time series, I once heard the statement that

> unit root test is less powerful.

I hereby have two questions:

1. What does it mean for a test to be powerful?
2. What causes the unit root test to be less powerful?

Comment: For the concept of power, please [search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=power+analysis+hypothesis).  "Less powerful" has no intrinsic meaning; your second question can only be answered if you tell us to what the unit root test is being compared.

Comment: [Power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power) is the probability of rejecting the null when its false. As whuber says, you can search on the site; there's a particular example of a power comparison [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80856/how-to-calculate-power-of-different-normality-tests-such-as-shapiro-wilk-ryan-t/80960#80960), for example. As for what causes a test to be less powerful, generally speaking, against some particular alternative, it's because there's information in the data that the test it's being compared to is using better than it.

Comment: Without more information about what it's being compared to and under what specific alternative, it's hard to say much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because part of it has been answered and the other part cannot be answered.