# Power of KStest

Tags: matlab

I have a basic question , I wanna to calculate the power of one sample kstest. Please help me out . I have the sample of 76 data. Calculated the h,p,k,cv for the given sample but not able to calculate the power .
thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is the same as for any test with broad alternatives, including most goodness of fit tests -- see the explanation [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80856/how-to-calculate-power-of-different-normality-tests-such-as-shapiro-wilk-ryan-t/80960#80960). In particular, consider the third sentence "*To compute the power you need to specify a particular alternative*"; that post then goes on to illustrate an approach to computing power for specific alternatives and sequences of alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the distribution of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic will vary greatly depending on the underlying distribution of the data  when the null hypothesis is false.  So you would need to specify exactly *how* the null is not true in order to even get started answering this question.  My guess is that you can't get a very satisfactory answer to this in general.